Using Python with Selenium and BeautifulSoup4 how can i get data after Javascript has loaded all elements on the page?
I'm trying to scrape data from a sandbox website just to practice and start using python to scrape web data.
I have managed to extract a lot of data using the basics however I have found an element that is loaded in dynamically after the initial page load.
My question is how to extract this data after the element has loaded in?
Here is my code I'm currently using:
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://sandbox.oxylabs.io/products')

results = []
other_results = []
status = []
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

for element in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'product-card'}):
    name = element.find('h4')
    if name not in results:
        results.append(name.text)
        
for b in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'product-card'}):
# Note the use of 'attrs' to again select an element with the specified class.
    name2 = b.find(attrs={'class': 'price-wrapper'})
    # stock = b.find(attrs={'class': 'price-wrapper'}).find_next_sibling('p')
    # status.append(stock.text)
    other_results.append(name2.text)
    print(b)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': results, 'Prices': other_results, 'Stock': status})
df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

The element im trying to get is the stock
An example of what it looks like when loaded in is
Out of Stock
However it does not appear in the print(b) for any of the elements
I tried using css selector and .find() however there are two issues with that which are out of stock items have a class of out-of-stock and in stock items have a class of in-stock.
I tried using an if statement to manually set a variable on if it has in-stock class then setting it to "In Stock" else "Out of Stock" however due to the element not existing it always returns out of stock.

The best way to do this is to use the api, the next best option is to scrape script#__NEXT_DATA__ from the static html, last resort is selenium. the reason you can't find the element is because you didnt' wait for everything to load.

I would never recommend anyone using selenium for web crawling, as it is only suitable for testing process.
To overcome how to crawl them exactly, even content generated from Javascript like ajax, it would be crawled as well from API partially. So you need to inspect Dev Tools (F12) -> Network and try to inspect them one by one request
From this method, I can find figure out 3 options to crawl
Let's put in a decorator to see the actual time run
from functools import wraps
import time

def timeit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def timeit_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f'Function {func.__name__}{args} {kwargs} Took {total_time:.4f} seconds')
        return result
    return timeit_wrapper

Method 1
Using Requests and BeautifulSoup, the idea is getting all pure HTML and parse it to BeautifulSoup. In this case, there is no Javascript to be generated later for showing 2 fields name and price, thus this is fine for pure HTML
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

@timeit
def crawl_using_html():
    # Function crawl_using_html() {} Took 48.6248 seconds
    results = []
    page = 1
    while True:
        url = f'https://sandbox.oxylabs.io/products?page={page}'

        sub_results = []
        content = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

        found_elements = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-card'})

        if len(found_elements) == 0:
            break

        for element in found_elements:
            name = element.find('h4')
            price = element.find('div', {'class': 'price-wrapper'})
            sub_results.append((name.text, price.text))
                
        page += 1
        results.extend(sub_results)
        print(sub_results)

crawl_using_html()

Method 2
If you looking at the Network, you may find the products.json from https://sandbox.oxylabs.io/_next/data/-0UsSqtBWVEoFjJOOUmuF/products.json, I will try to switch paging and see it could put parameter page like Method 1
So you don't need to even using BeautifulSoup and the code will look like this
import json

@timeit
def crawl_using_paging_api():
    # Function crawl_using_paging_api() {} Took 41.0094 seconds
    results = []
    page = 1
    while True:
        url = f'https://sandbox.oxylabs.io/_next/data/-0UsSqtBWVEoFjJOOUmuF/products.json?page={page}'

        sub_results = []
        content = requests.get(url).json()
        
        products = content['pageProps']['products']
        if len(products) == 0:
            break

        for element in products:
            sub_results.append((element['game_name'], f'{element["user_score"]},99 €'))
                
        page += 1
        results.extend(sub_results)
        print(sub_results)

crawl_using_paging_api()

It's also funny that we have no price in the API, that price is getting from user_score and append with ,99 €
Method 3
During playing around with Network inspection, I saw the API is getting complete products without paging, so it can shorten crawling time less than 1 second
@timeit
def crawl_using_full_api():
    # Function crawl_using_full_api() {} Took 0.8606 seconds
    results = []

    url = f'https://scraping-demo-api-json-server.vercel.app/products'

    products = requests.get(url).json()
    
    for element in products:
        results.append((element['game_name'], f'{element["user_score"]},99 €'))
            
    print(results)

crawl_using_full_api()

